# Consultas Multitablas

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Estimados estoy realizando una consulta a mi base de datos con INNER JION pero me da un error en la conexión, que el parámetro

```
Advertencia: mysqli_query (): No se pudo obtener mysqli en C: \ wamp \ www \ csobeta \ consorcio \ flotaoperativa.php en la línea 143.

mysqli_fetch_array () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, nulo dado en C: \ wamp \ www \ csobeta \ consorcio \ flotaoperativa.php en la línea 144.
```

A continuación muestro el código de consulta, ya que debo realizar diferentes consultas para que el usuario obtenga información.

```
<?php

$query="SELECT Al.Id_Bus,Al.Habilitacion_Bus,Al.Socio_Bus,Al.Cédula_Socio,Al.Placa_Bus,Al.Año_Bus,Al.Marca_Bus,
Op.Id_Operadora



FROM buses Al

INNER JOIN operadoras Op ON AL.Id_Operadora=Op.Id_Operadora";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

 echo'    
 <tr>
 <td>'.$fila['Id_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Habilitacion_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Socio_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Cédula_Socio'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Placa_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Año_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Marca_Bus'].'</td>
 <td>'.$fila['Id_Operadora'].'</td>

 </tr>
    ';
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Pareciera que tienes problema en los que almacenas en :$conexion verifica que tengas todos los parámetros correctos, estas conectandote a una base localmente?

Comment: `$result` es nulo, sea porque no has podido conectar correctamente a la BD, sea porque hay un error de sintaxis en la instrucción SQL que envías. Revisa ambas cosas y cuéntanos el resultado.

Comment: @Santiago estimado si justamente a un servidor local a Wampserver, justo verifique la conexión y esta correcta.

Comment: Estimado está es mi conexión local la cual tengo en otro formulario. <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd");
if(!$conexion){

  echo "error al conextarse ";
}
else{
  echo "se conecto";

}
 ?>

Comment: alparecer te falta importar el archivo donde tienes la conexion tal vez es por eso que no te reconoce uno de los parametros el mysqli_query ().  ya importaste el archivo con : include("conexion.php");  a flotaoperativa.php ?

Comment: @Santiago si esta incluido en el formulario de flotaoperativa.php pero no sé si esta bien realizado el llamado al formulario en donde está la conexión.       <?php 

include ("conexion.php");

echo "Se ha conectado correctamente ";




 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport"    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author"      content="Consorcio Sur Occidental">

Comment: Intenta colocarlo de esta forma(dentro de tu consulta): <?php include("conexion.php");          $query="SELECT Al.Id_Bus,Al.Habilitacion_Bus,Al.Socio_Bus,Al.Cédula_Socio,Al.Placa_Bus,Al.Año_Bus,Al.Marca_Bus,
Op.Id_Operadora


FROM buses Al ......   Otra cosa:  la consulta ya la probaste en el motor de base de datos y te funciona? tal vez no esta bien realizada la consulta,  y quita el:   echo "Se ha conectado correctamente ";

Comment: @Santiago en la bd las consultas se realiza normalmente pero me sale un error.                                                                                                                 Tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; consulte el manual que corresponde a la versión de su servidor MySQL para conocer la sintaxis correcta para usar cerca de ' dula_Socio, Al.Placa_Bus, Al.Año_Bus, Al.Marca_Bus, Op.Id_Operadora FROM buses' en la línea 1                                                                      es por eso que voy a cambiar los nombres de los campos en la bd, está bien ?

Comment: AH ENTONCES ES ESO, si la consulta te funciona bien el el motor de base de datos de seguro te funcionara en el .php ,era que  comencemos por ahí jeje. Te recomiendo usar "AS" pars el alias , osea : from buses as Al

Comment: @Santiago muchas gracias por su tiempo y su apoyo, bendiciones estimado.

Comment: , y otra cosa no es recomendable  que tus nombres de tablas y atributos de estas tengan o contengan acentos o tildes, ya que tendras que usar utf-8 para que pueda reconocer alfabeto en español, ya que  en ingles no hay las ñ  ni las tildes en las palabras. evita ponerle tildes a tus nombres de atributos y tablas.

Comment: @Santiago gracias no tome en consideración eso, ya los cambie todos los nombres de los campos.

Comment: si, es mejor así evitaras frustraciones, pues puede estar todo bien pero por una tilde o ñ puedes tener problemas.